# Python integer testing

Tags: python

```
def isinteger(x):
    while x > 0.0:
        x = x - 1.0
    if x < 0.0:
        return 0.0
    elif x == 0:
        return 1.0

d = input('')
print isinteger(d)
```

The code is somewhat self explanatory. I'm using it for a fractran interpreter. Here is my problem: I input a fraction, such as 22/7, and I get a 1 as my output. Does it have something to do with python's IO?

Comment: You might also consider a more efficient way of checking to see if `x` is an integer. For instance `if x % 1 == 0 return 1 else return 0`

Answer (score 5):

The `input` function evaluates your 22/7 exactly the same way as if it had been entered into the python interpreter. Since both 22 and 7 are integers you get an integer division with a result of 3. If you want float division, enter either `22.0/7` or `22/7.0` both of which result in `3.146...`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using python 2, inputting "22/7" directly leads to integer division, i.e. it rounds your input down to 3, thus the algorithm returns 1. Try inputting 22.0/7 instead.

Also, you might want to consider faster alternatives to this algorithm if you're using it for anything real. Possibilities:

```
def isinteger(x):
    return int(x) == x

def isinteger(x):
    return isinstance(x, int)
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you!
Is there anyway to have 22/7 be taken as 22.0/7.0? For fractran, you have to write a lot of fractions, so it would make it less cumbersome.

Comment: If you use python 3 instead of python 2, it automatically performs floating point division so 22/7 is treated as 22.0/7.0 (integer division needs to be forced with 22//7). I'm not sure how you could do that in python 2.

Comment: In python 2 you can put `from __future__ import division` at the top of your program

Answer (score 2):

`22.0/7` vs `22/7` aside, there is another problem with this approach: it does not work in the majority of programming languages, because of [the way floating point numbers are represented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). For example, using your original function:

```
In [37]: isinteger(190.000000000000000001)
Out[37]: 1.0
```

Using Sean's `int(x) == x` suggestion:

```
In [39]: x = 190.000000000000000001
In [40]: int(x) == x
Out[40]: True
```

I realize it doesn't directly address the question, but I hope it will prevent a future one :)

Comment: That's not a problem with this approach--`x` *is* an integer.  Due to rounding, `190.000000000000000001 == 190`.  No algorithm is going to give any other answer, since the input is simply 190.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: By 'this approach' I mean the high level: 'writing an interpreter that tries to treat floating point values specially using `==` checks' instead of, say, using type tags. It's unclear from the question what the intent is of the `isinteger` check, so I figured it is worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for integer for example for finding big perfect squares, you must consider inaccuracy of binary representations (abs is not needed for positive numbers, but is needed for negative numbers):

```
x = -190.00000000001
print int(x) == x

epsilon = 1E-10

def isinteger(n):
    " near enoungh to pass as integer considering round of errors "
    return abs(n-int(n)) < epsilon

print isinteger(x)
```

Implied eval of Python2 is considered too powerfull to be safe. If you want to input numbers instead of let user to give any formula (and in every case you need to add try...except handling for the users input):

```
number = raw_input('Give number: ')
number = int(number) if all(c.isdigit() for c in number) else float(number)
print number
```

Answer (score 0):

your inputs are both integers so it results in giving 3 as input thereby it produces 1 as output.